# Problemas ao fazer upload de imagens com a biblioteca dropzone

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou usando a biblioteca **dropzone**, ela está funcionando o único problema é que os arquivos selecionados não chegam ao servidor, sempre me retorna **Undefined index files**, o que poderia ser?

O formulário está assim:

```
<h4 class="card-title">Escolha as imagens do seu anúncio</h4>
<form method="POST" id="myFirstDropzone" action="<?= base_url('Anunciante/adicionarImagens'); ?>" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fallback"> 
      <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple> 
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
 Dropzone.options.myFirstDropzone = {
            paramName: "files", 
            maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 3,
            maxFiles: 3
});


$("#btn-adicionar-img").click(function(){
   $("#myFirstDropzone").submit(); 
});
```

Controllador

```
public function adicionarImagens(){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_FILES['files']);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
    $this->anunciante->adicionaImagens($_FILES['files'], $this->session->userdata('id_anuncio'));
}
```

Comment: qual é o resultado de `var_dump($_FILES['files']);`?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered



Severity: Notice


Message:  Undefined index: files

Comment: O nome do seu `input` é `files[]`, você não deveria indexar da mesma forma em `php`? Seria `$_FILES['files[]']`

Comment: Lógico que não, isso nem existe cara, estou mandando uma array com o nome files, em cada posição vai uma imagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFirstDropzone" action="<?= base_url('Anunciante/adicionarImagens'); ?>" class="dropzone">

                </form><button type="button" id="btn-upload" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar imagens</button>
```

Quando clicar no botão vai iniciar o upload dos arquivos:

```
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myFirstDropzone', {
            paramName: "files",
            maxFilesize: 3.0,
            maxFiles: 4,
            parallelUploads: 10000,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false
        });

        $('#btn-upload').on('click', function () {
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
```

Bem simples galera, pra quem precisar está ai!